# Hibernate Envers implementation of custom composite type

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, kotlin, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to audit my custom Postgres type with Hibernate Envers, also I'm using Quarkus with Kotlin and panache repository.

My Postgres setup:

```
CREATE TYPE money_and_currency AS (amount integer, currency varchar(3));
CREATE TABLE example_table (
    "id" uuid,
    "maximum_value" money_and_currency,
    "minimum_value" money_and_currency
);
```

My Entity setup:

```
@Table(name = "example_table")
@Entity
@Audited
class ExpectedPaymentEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false)

    @Column(name = "maximum_value")
    @Embedded
    var maximumValue: MoneyAndCurrency ?= null

    @Column(name = "minimum_value")
    @Embedded
    var minimumValue: MoneyAndCurrency ?= null
}

@Embeddable
@Struct(name = "money_and_currency")
class MoneyAndCurrency(
    val amount: Int,
    val currency: String
)
```

I got this error when trying to compile my project:

> Column 'amount' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'project.transaction.adapter.out.hibernate.entity.ExpectedPaymentEntity_AUD' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)

I tried adding this line to my entity and indeed the code compiles, but nothing is audited when I run my db operations. I want to audit these two fields in the way they are persisted